# Apache Zeppelin 0.8.1 Python Interpreter on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to set up Apache Zeppelin 0.8.1 on Windows 10.

I'm mainly looking to run the python interpreter in an effort to call it later via rest api, but I'm having a hard time getting the interpreter to run.

I've added python into the path environement variable and can now be called in cmd:

`python`

in Zeppelin's python interpreter configuration, the property zeppelin.python by default has the value `python` and it is covered in documentation that this is enough if the command is in the path.

When I try to invoke the interpreter on a simple command such as `'%python print 1+1'`, I get this stack trace:

```
 org.apache.thrift.TException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.createInterpreter(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:320)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Processor$createInterpreter.getResult(RemoteInterpreterService.java:1799)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Processor$createInterpreter.getResult(RemoteInterpreterService.java:1784)
  at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
  at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
  at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.createInterpreter(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:309)
  ... 8 more
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
  at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreter.<init>(PythonInterpreter.java:105)
  ... 13 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
  at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
  at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonInterpreter.<init>(PythonInterpreter.java:102)
  ... 13 more
```

Things I tried:

- python versions 2 & 3
- Zeppelin property set to the absolute path (also covered in documentation)
- JDK 7 instead of 8, but this complains of major minor version

I also noticed that Zeppelin logs folder is always empty which seems to be abnormal.

**Edit:**

I have not solved the issue on my localhost, I've swiched to the dockerized version which works well out of the box, dropping this comment for Zeppelin new comers like myself to start with Docker.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance!